# Есть ли какая-то выгода от использования Dispatcher в WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

В WinForms можно воспользоваться классов WPF- Dispatcher для доступа к UI из разных потоков.

Однако, есть ли в нем какой-то профит по сравнение с использованием стандартного Invoke? Есть ли приципиальные отличия, между Invoke и Dispatcher?

Со стороны если смотреть, то когда, вроде, столько же нужно.

Comment: Да вроде бы нету, зачем тащить лишнюю концепцию из другого фреймворка?

Answer (score 0):

По свой семантике они абсолютно эквиваленты. Да и применение у них похожее.

WPF:

```
  if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
  {
       //action
  }
  else
  {
       Dispatcher.Invoke( () => /* action */ );
  }
```

WinForms:

```
  if (this.InvokeRequired)
      this.Invoke(() => /* action */);
  else
      //action
```

Но конечно лучше все таки использовать `SynchronizationContext`. Я считаю что это лучше будет для глаз тем более при работе с WPF с использованием MVVM. Да Вы знаете что некоторое действие должно произойти в некотором UI потоке, но к чему тянуть некоторые специальные вызовы/библиотеки/зависимости, тем более которые принадлежат фреймворку UI, в слой VM? Лучше конечно же использовать контекст синхронизации.

Вот например очень хорошая статья : [Stephen Cleary. Parallel Computing - It's All About the SynchronizationContext](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2011/february/msdn-magazine-parallel-computing-it-s-all-about-the-synchronizationcontext)

Еще по поводу разницы между диспатчерами WPF и WinForms - у диспатчера в WPF более высокий уровень абстракции, так же есть приоритеты и разные другие вещи, которые могут быть полезны и придают большей гибкости.